# Robotframework. I can't input text to login form by id email

Tags: authentication, robotframework

How to select an element with `id="email"` ?

```
<form id="login-form"> 
<div class="input-field login-elm-wrap" css="1"> 
<i class="prefix material-icons">email</i> 
<input id="email" type="email" class="login-elm validate" required="true" autocomplete="off"><label for="email">Email</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
Click Element   xpath=//*[@id="email"]
Input text     xpath=//*[@id="email"]    abc@xyz.com

OR

Click Element   id=email
Input text     id=email   abc@xyz.com
```